# Click link, Crawler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

Is it possible somehow to click this div which is generating a URL which I need to crawl? Here's the HTML of the button which I need to click:

```
<div class="md_playbtn md_action" data-action="play" data-object="furl" data-player="html5">
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="filmpricePlay">
        <span style='color: #52ff56'>nemokamai</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And my code is:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.test.in/slaptasis-rastas-lietuviu-kalba');
$vidUrl = $html->find('div.md_playbtn', 0);

echo $vidUrl;

echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setInterval(function(){
                $('.md_playbtn').click();
            }, 1);
        });
    </script>";

$vid = $html->find('div.md_player > video >source',0)->src;
echo $vid;

?>
```

Comment: Where is the code that is generating the URL you need to crawl?

Comment: <div class="md_playbtn md_action" data-action="play" data-object="furl" data-player="html5">
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-play-circle-o"></i>
    </div>
    <div id="filmpricePlay">
        <span style='color: #52ff56'>nemokamai</span>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: this one, if client click it, it generate another div wich have url wich i need. Sorry for my bad english:/

Comment: You're not showing the code that generates the URL.

Comment: Actualy i dont know how its make it, i only know if pressing that div its creating another one

Comment: im trying to crawl video url form this page: https://www.filmai.in/slaptasis-rastas-lietuviu-kalba.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to automatically interact with an element on a page that you don't control. If the video src URL is not created client side, then you'll have to interact with the page, or reverse engineer the architecture and replay the network conversation. Please take into account that crawling pages might be illegal in your region, or it might be prohibited by the site ToS. I'll provide an example here, but use it at your own risk.

You can try opening the developer console on the page in question, and try: `document.querySelector('div.md_playbtn').click();`. After that completes, try `document.querySelector('div.md_player > video >source').getAttribute('src');` to get the video URL. This is untested.

Comment: Seems like they have protection on server side, į tryied to copy whole page and movie cannot be loaded. Maybe somebody have other solutions..